# Ionic 4 navigation error if don't specify whole path

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have a login path like this

`{ path: 'login', loadChildren: 'src/app/auth/login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },`

If i insert tabs into my app ,and define paths

```
path: '',
component: TabsPage,
children: [
  { path: 'settings', loadChildren:'./settings/settings.module#SettingsPageModule' },]
```

When i try to run again my app i have errors like this

"ERROR in Could not resolve module /app/auth/login/login.module relative to src/app/app-routing.module.ts"

then when i specify the route with "src" login path and tabs path

`{ path: 'login', loadChildren: 'src/app/pages/auth/login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },`

I've seen many tutorials but no one had this problem.
I solved it this way but I don't know if it's the right one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet in your routing-module:

**app-routing-module.ts**

```
{ path: 'login', loadChildren: './pages/auth/login/login.module#LoginPageModule' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error says it all. You need to specify the routes **relative** to app-routing.module.ts.

> "ERROR in Could not resolve module /app/auth/login/login.module relative to src/app/app-routing.module.ts"

If the login folder is in the app directory, the relative route to the PageModule would be:

```js
{ path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
```

In your case the relative route is:

```js
{ path: 'login', loadChildren: './pages/auth/login/login.module#LoginPageModule' }
```

All routes defined in `app-routing.module.ts` will show no tabbar. If you want to set the tabbar as your entry point, you need to point the default route (`''`) to your tabs module. Then define all routes who need to show the tabbar in `tabs.router.module.ts`.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
{ path: '', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
```

**tabs.router.module.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../home/home.module#HomePageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
// ...
```

Comment: This error occurs only when I insert the tabs, if i delete them . It's a normal thing ? Thank you.

Comment: @ChrisTrasp what do you mean by inserting the tabs? The error occurs when going to your settings page?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer , i'm sorry, i can't give you like for my rating . Pretend that i did it :D @Tomas Vancoillie